# Why is HTML returned by requests different from the real page HTML?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a webpage for getting some data to work with, one of the web pages I want to scrape is this one https://www.etoro.com/people/sparkliang/portfolio, the problem comes when I scrape the web page using:

```
import requests

h=requests.get('https://www.etoro.com/people/sparkliang/portfolio')
h.content
```

And gives me a completely different result HTML from the original, for example adding a lot of meta kind and deleting the text or type HTML variables I am searching for.

For example imagine I want to scrape:

```
<p ng-if=":: item.IsStock" class="i-portfolio-table-hat-fullname ng-binding ng-scope">Shopify Inc.</p>
```

I use a command like this:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    import requests

    html_text = requests.get('https://www.etoro.com/people/sparkliang/portfolio').text
    print(html_text)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text,'lxml')

    job = soup.find('p', class_='i-portfolio-table-hat-fullname ng-binding ng-scope').text
```

This will return me Shopify Inc.
But it doesn't because the html code y load or get from the web page with the requests' library, gets me another complete different html.

I want to know how to get the original html code from the web page.
If you use cntl-f for searching to a keyword like **Shopify Inc** it wont be even in the code i get from the requests python library

Comment: The final page is generated in DOM by javascript.

Comment: And how i convert from DOM to html in python?

Comment: [This should answer your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59727663/why-request-get-returning-wrong-page-content)

Answer (score 3):

It happens because the page uses dynamic javascript to create the DOM elements. So you won't be able to accomplish it using requests. Instead you should use selenium with a webdriver and wait for the elements to be created before scraping.

You can try downloading ChromeDriver executable [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). And if you paste it in the same folder as your script you can run:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "\\chromedriver.exe" # CHANGE THIS IF NOT SAME FOLDER
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)

url = 'https://www.etoro.com/people/sparkliang/portfolio'
driver.get(url)
html_text = driver.page_source

jobs = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p.i-portfolio-table-hat-fullname'))
)
for job in jobs:
    print(job.text)
```

Here we use selenium with `WebDriverWait` and `EC` to ensure that all the elements wil exist when we try to scrape the info we're looking for.

#### Outputs

```
Facebook
Apple
Walt Disney
Alibaba
JD.com
Mastercard
...
```