# Search by class with beautiful soup (python) not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the date, and the minimum and maximum temperatures from the site https://www.ipma.pt/pt/otempo/prev.localidade.hora/#Porto&Gondomar.
I want to find all of the divs with the date class and all the spans with the tempMin and tempMax classes, so I wrote

```
pagina2= "https://www.ipma.pt/pt/otempo/prev.localidade.hora/#Porto&Gondomar"
client2= uReq(pagina2)
pagina2bs= soup(client2.read(), "html.parser")
client2.close()

data = pagina2bs.find_all("div", class_="date")
minT = pagina2bs.find_all("span", class_="tempMin")
maxT = pagina2bs.find_all("span", class_="tempMax")
```

but all I get are empty lists. I've compared this with similar code and I can't see where I made a mistake, since [there are clearly tags with these classes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSIgf.png)

Comment: The page uses dynamic javascript to load the content. You should use other methods, like selenium, instead of request.

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65186906/why-is-html-returned-by-requests-different-from-the-real-page-html/65187344#65187344) answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my perspective it has to do with the content of the pagina2bs variable. You are passing the right variables to the **find_all** method.

Use selenium to get the html of that website.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import html5lib
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path='C:/Users/**USERNAME**/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
startUrl = "https://www.ipma.pt/pt/otempo/prev.localidade.hora/#Porto&Gondomar"
driver.get(startUrl)
html = driver.page_source

soup = bs(html,features="html5lib")
divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="date")
print(divs)
```

Install all the needed packages and a the selenium chrome driver. Link to this chromedriver in the code like I did on my machine.

Comment: You're right, pagina2bs doesn't contain that part. Here is the variable (https://pastebin.com/bWC3AhGQ). Is it because the html is too big or something like that?

Comment: No the html is not to big, but just does not contain the right information.
I adapted my answer. Now you can use the code to get the information you want from that site!